# Javascript array in combo boxes

Tags: javascript

I have been given an array in the following format and need to put it into two drop down boxes one with make and the other with model based on the first selection. (the actual array is huge, but I have just included the first few)

```
var aMember = [{
    "Make": "other",
    "Models": ["other"]
}, {
    "Make": "Boat",
    "Models": ["Over 21 ft.", "Under 21 ft."]
}, {
    "Make": "Motorcycle",
    "Models": ["Over 600cc", "Under 600cc"]
}];
```

I need to have a make combo box with Other, Boat and Motorcycle, which when selected populates the second combo box with the options.

I have done almost no JavaScript before, but have tried the following, which does not work.
I really don't know if I am anywhere near to what I need.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var cars =[{"Make":"other","Models":["other"]},{"Make":"Boat","Models":["Over 21 ft.","Under 21 ft."]},{"Make":"Motorcycle","Models":["Over 600cc","Under 600cc"]}];

function populateDropdown(drop, items) {
   drop.empty();
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      drop.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + items[i].Make + '</option>');
   }
   drop.show();
}

populateDropdown( $('#Makes'), cars );


$('#Models').change(function() {
   var modelIndex = $(this).val();
   var model = Models[modelIndex ];

   populateDropdown( $('#Models'), cars.Models);

});

</script>
</head>
<body onload = "populateDropdown( $('#Makes'), cars );">
<form>


MAKE:
<select name = 'Makes'>
</select>
MODEL:
<select name = 'Models'>
</select>

</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `$.grep` to filter out the current make, and then fetch the models of that make.
- You can use `$.map` to map the array with all data to an array of makes.
- `$.each` can be used.
- You can use `$("<option>").val(...).text(...)` to build the `option` a little cleaner.
- You need `$(function() {...})` to wait until the DOM is ready.
- `drop.show()` is not needed since both `select`s are already visible
- You're populating `Models` on `Models`'s change event. I think you mean to run that on `Makes`'s change event.
- You're using `name` instead of `id`. Also you should not use spaces around the `=` in HTML attributes.

This is a corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/zJTnw/1/.

```
$(function(){
    var cars = [
        {"Make":"other",
         "Models": ["other"]},

        {"Make":"Boat",
         "Models": ["Over 21 ft.","Under 21 ft."]},

        {"Make":"Motorcycle",
         "Models": ["Over 600cc","Under 600cc"]}
    ];

    function populateDropdown(drop, items) {
        drop.empty();

        $.each(items, function(i, v) { // `i` is index, `v` is element
            drop.append($("<option>").val(v).text(v));
        });
    }

    populateDropdown($('#Makes'), $.map(cars, function(x) {
        return x.Make; // map `cars` to an array of makes
    }));

    $('#Makes').change(function() {
        var make = $(this).val();

        var item = $.grep(cars, function(x) { // get item of this make
            return x.Make === make;
        });

        populateDropdown($('#Models'), item[0].Models); // populate with models
    });
});
```

Comment: I can see that this works in the example, but can you explain how the $(function() notation works? do I put it into a <script> block?

Comment: @ben townend: Yes, just wrap all code inside `$(function() {` and `});`.  In this case `$(function() {` can just follow the `<script>` tag, and `</script>` can follow the `});`.

Comment: thanks. I have tried this and still get blank drop downs I have my code here http://shrib.com/ben Sorry, I know it should work!

Comment: @ben townend: I copied that code and it does work. Are you sure you're not missing anything on your real page? You need to include jQuery, of course.

Comment: thanks that was it. 1 last thing when the page loads the make combo box has other selected but the model one is blank is there a way that I could get it to say Other - Other on load? Thanks

Comment: @ben townend: You could populate at page load as well, like `$('#Makes').change()` to trigger a change event programatically.

Answer (score 0):

the `$(#Makes)` searches for the ID! not for the name! change the select `name='Makes'` to `id='makes'`

Comment: This is true, but there are several other issues that will still prevent it from working correctly even with that change.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var cars =[{"Make":"other","Models":["other"]},{"Make":"Boat","Models":["Over 21 ft.","Under 21 ft."]},{"Make":"Motorcycle","Models":["Over 600cc","Under 600cc"]}];

function populateDropdown(drop, items) {
   drop.empty();
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      drop.append('<option value=' + i + '>' + items[i].Make + '</option>');
   }
   drop.show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    populateDropdown( $('#makes'), cars );

    $('#makes').change(function() {
       var index = $(this).val();
       var make = cars[index];

       populateDropdown( $('#models'), make.Models);
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>


MAKE:
<select id="make">
</select>

MODEL:
<select id="models">
</select>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This uses `id="make"` instead of `name="make"` which is what makes the `#make` selector work. It also applies the `.change()` event handler to `#makes` instead of `#models` (you're making the change when the MAKE is changed), and it uses `$(document).ready()` to make sure all the setup work happens only after the document is ready. Trying to attach the event handlers or edit the `<select>` boxes too early will not work.